# What is the SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY in `gem environment`?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I hit `gem environment` in my linux system. I got the following output:

```
 - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.4.6
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.2.1 (2015-02-26 patchlevel 85) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/rk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home/rk/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/rk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /home/rk/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/rk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1
     - /home/rk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "gem" => "--no-document"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /usr/local/heroku/bin
     - /home/rk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin
     - /home/rk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/bin
     - /home/rk/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /usr/bin
     - /sbin
     - /bin
     - /usr/games
     - /usr/local/games
     - /home/rk/.rvm/bin
     - /home/rk/.rvm/bin
     - /home/rk/android-studio/bin
     - /home/rk/.rvm/bin
```

I went to explore the spec cache directory. The following is the result of `~/.gem/specs $ find .` It looks like a place where all the gemspecs are stored. I see two folders `api.rubygems.org%443` and  `rubygems.org%443`. Why are there two folders and what does the 443 at the end specify?(permissions?). can you elaborate a bit on this?

```
.
./api.rubygems.org%443
./api.rubygems.org%443/specs.4.8
./api.rubygems.org%443/quick
./api.rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8
./api.rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/actionview-4.2.1.gemspec
./api.rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/bundler-unload-1.0.2.gemspec
./api.rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/activesupport-4.2.1.gemspec
./api.rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/actionmailer-4.2.1.gemspec
./api.rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/listen-2.10.1.gemspec
./api.rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/ffi-1.9.8.gemspec
./api.rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/thor-0.19.1.gemspec
./api.rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/bundler-1.10.6.gemspec
./api.rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/activemodel-4.2.1.gemspec
./api.rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/rubygems-bundler-1.4.4.gemspec
./api.rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/globalid-0.3.5.gemspec
./api.rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/mercenary-0.3.5.gemspec
./api.rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/jekyll-2.5.3.gemspec
./api.rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/jekyll-sass-converter-1.3.0.gemspec
./api.rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/libv8-3.16.14.11-x86_64-linux.gemspec
./api.rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/loofah-2.0.2.gemspec
./api.rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/sass-3.2.14.gemspec
./api.rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/rspec-3.3.0.gemspec
./api.rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/compass-1.0.3.gemspec
./api.rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/activerecord-4.2.1.gemspec
./api.rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/sprockets-3.2.0.gemspec
./api.rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/rack-test-0.6.3.gemspec
./api.rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/safe_yaml-1.0.4.gemspec
./api.rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/nokogiri-1.6.6.2.gemspec
./api.rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/pygments.rb-0.6.3.gemspec
./api.rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/toml-0.1.2.gemspec
./api.rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/executable-hooks-1.3.2.gemspec
./api.rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/railties-4.2.1.gemspec
./api.rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/liquid-2.6.2.gemspec
./api.rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/erubis-2.7.0.gemspec
./api.rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/kramdown-1.8.0.gemspec
./api.rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/rails-4.2.1.gemspec
./api.rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/tmuxinator-0.7.0.gemspec
./api.rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/arel-6.0.0.gemspec
./api.rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/celluloid-0.16.0.gemspec
./api.rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/jekyll-gist-1.2.1.gemspec
./api.rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/hitimes-1.2.2.gemspec
./api.rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/actionpack-4.2.1.gemspec
./api.rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/timers-4.0.1.gemspec
./api.rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/rack-1.6.1.gemspec
./api.rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/fast-stemmer-1.0.2.gemspec
./api.rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/builder-3.2.2.gemspec
./api.rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/json-1.4.6.gemspec
./api.rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/sprockets-rails-2.3.1.gemspec
./api.rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/pg-0.18.1.gemspec
./api.rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/rails-deprecated_sanitizer-1.0.3.gemspec
./api.rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/posix-spawn-0.3.11.gemspec
./api.rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/rubygems-update-2.6.1.gemspec
./api.rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/compass-0.12.3.gemspec
./api.rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/thread_safe-0.3.5.gemspec
./api.rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/tzinfo-1.2.2.gemspec
./api.rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/bundler-1.11.2.gemspec
./api.rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/jekyll-watch-1.2.1.gemspec
./api.rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/rails-html-sanitizer-1.0.2.gemspec
./api.rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/rails-dom-testing-1.0.6.gemspec
./api.rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/sqlite3-1.3.11.gemspec
./api.rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/chunky_png-1.3.4.gemspec
./api.rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/compass-import-once-1.0.5.gemspec
./api.rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/colorator-0.1.gemspec
./api.rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/activejob-4.2.1.gemspec
./api.rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/cucumber-2.1.0.gemspec
./api.rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/therubyracer-0.12.2.gemspec
./api.rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/redcarpet-3.3.2.gemspec
./api.rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/classifier-reborn-2.0.3.gemspec
./api.rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/parslet-1.5.0.gemspec
./api.rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/fssm-0.2.10.gemspec
./api.rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/jekyll-paginate-1.1.0.gemspec
./api.rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/json-1.8.3.gemspec
./api.rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/i18n-0.7.0.gemspec
./api.rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/gherkin3-3.1.1.gemspec
./api.rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/mail-2.6.3.gemspec
./api.rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/compass-core-1.0.3.gemspec
./api.rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/rb-inotify-0.9.5.gemspec
./api.rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/sass-3.4.14.gemspec
./api.rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/yajl-ruby-1.2.1.gemspec
./api.rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/pg-0.18.2.gemspec
./api.rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/jekyll-coffeescript-1.0.1.gemspec
./api.rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/rb-fsevent-0.9.5.gemspec
./api.rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/blankslate-2.1.2.4.gemspec
./api.rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/cucumber-core-1.3.0.gemspec
./api.rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/ref-1.0.5.gemspec
./api.rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/mini_portile-0.6.2.gemspec
./api.rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/mime-types-2.6.1.gemspec
./rubygems.org%443
./rubygems.org%443/latest_specs.4.8
./rubygems.org%443/specs.4.8
./rubygems.org%443/quick
./rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8
./rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/rake-0.5.3.gemspec
./rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/rouge-1.11.1.gemspec
./rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/rake-10.0.2.gemspec
./rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/bundler-unload-1.0.2.gemspec
./rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/bundler-1.10.6.gemspec
./rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/rake-0.8.2.gemspec
./rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/rake-0.6.0.gemspec
./rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/rubygems-bundler-1.4.4.gemspec
./rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/pathutil-0.14.0.gemspec
./rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/rake-0.8.3.gemspec
./rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/rake-0.4.12.gemspec
./rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/rake-10.0.3.gemspec
./rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/forwardable-extended-2.6.0.gemspec
./rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/rake-0.9.2.2.gemspec
./rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/rake-0.9.3.gemspec
./rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/rake-0.5.0.gemspec
./rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/rake-0.9.1.gemspec
./rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/rake-0.9.5.gemspec
./rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/rake-0.5.4.gemspec
./rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/rake-0.9.2.gemspec
./rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/executable-hooks-1.3.2.gemspec
./rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/rake-10.0.1.gemspec
./rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/liquid-3.0.6.gemspec
./rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/rake-0.9.4.gemspec
./rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/rake-0.4.15.gemspec
./rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/rake-0.8.4.gemspec
./rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/rake-10.1.0.gemspec
./rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/rake-0.4.10.gemspec
./rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/rake-10.0.4.gemspec
./rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/rake-0.8.6.gemspec
./rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/rake-0.4.11.gemspec
./rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/rake-10.1.1.gemspec
./rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/rake-0.4.9.gemspec
./rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/rake-0.7.3.gemspec
./rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/resque_unit-0.4.8.gemspec
./rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/jekyll-3.2.1.gemspec
./rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/rake-0.8.7.gemspec
./rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/rake-0.9.6.gemspec
./rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/rake-0.8.0.gemspec
./rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/rake-0.8.1.gemspec
./rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/rake-10.0.0.gemspec
./rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/rake-0.8.5.gemspec
./rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/rake-0.6.2.gemspec
./rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/rake-0.4.8.gemspec
./rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/rake-0.9.0.gemspec
./rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/colorator-1.1.0.gemspec
./rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/rake-0.7.1.gemspec
./rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/rake-0.4.14.gemspec
./rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/rake-0.7.0.gemspec
./rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/rake-0.7.2.gemspec
./rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/rake-0.4.13.gemspec
```